# Masonary reload item not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am trying to do gallery portfolio with help of masonry and custom click event. I can hide show images with the click event, but when hide show event complete masonry not reset to again.

[link](http://dayfortune.com/pic_click/index_05.html)

Here is jQuery code:

```
var pmo = "#p-masonry_outer";
var ppt = "#p-portfolio_typs";
$('' + ppt + ' li span').on('click', function() {
            $('' + ppt + ' li span').removeClass('p-active_work');
            $(this).addClass('p-active_work');
            var WorkRel = $(this).data("cat");
            if (WorkRel != "0") {
                $("" + pmo + " > div").hide();
                $(".p-masonry a").attr('data-lightbox', '');
                $("" + pmo + " > div").each(function() {
                    var WorkAttrStrip = $(this).data('cat');
                    var WorkAttr = WorkAttrStrip.split(",");
                    if ($.inArray(WorkRel + "", WorkAttr) !== -1) {
                        $(this).show;
                    }
                });
                var $container = $('.js-masonry');
                $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $container.masonry();
                });
            } else {
                $("" + pmo + " > div").fadeIn("slow");
            }
            return false;
        }
```